# Inverse method for discrete variables in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do the inverse method for a discrete variable, but I don't get anything (if I print the sample I get only one number, not a sample). How do I make this work correctly?

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def inversao_discreto(p,M):
    amostra=np.zeros(M)
    acum=np.zeros(len(p))
    acum[:]=p
    for i in range(1, len(acum)):
        acum[i]+=acum[i-1]
    r=rd.random_sample(M)
    for i in range(M):
        i=0
        k=0
        while(r[k]>acum[i]):
            i+=1
            amostra=i
    return amostra
model=np.array([0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.4])
sample=inversao_discreto(model,10000)
```

Comment: You're overwriting your whole result to a new number with this line: `amostra=i`

Comment: How? amostra=i is to associate a number to the probability thas was accepted. i generate a number (r=rd.random_sample(M)) than comparate to the probability in the acum, after that i cannot add the probabilty to amostra, i have to add the numbert of the event.

Comment: You literally make amostra into a single number. You don't do `amostra[index]=something` (like you did with `acum`). You literally do `amostra=i`, where `i` is a single number.

Comment: i understand, i missed that, but how can add the event i to amostra?i tried but i couldnt solve it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could understand, you want to implement the [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) for [discrete variables](https://www.win.tue.nl/~marko/2WB05/lecture8.pdf), which works like this:

```
Given a probability distribution `p`
Given a number of samples `M`
Calculate the cumulative probability distribution function `acum` from `p`
Generate `M` uniformly distributed samples and store into `r`
For each sample `r[i]`
    Get the index where the cumulative distribution `acum` is larger or equal to the sample `r[i]`
    Store this value into `amostra[i]`
```

If my understanding is correct, then your code is *almost* there. Your mistake is only in the last `for` loop. Your variable `i` is tracking the position of your samples stored in `r`. Then, `k` will keep track of where in the accumulator `acum` you are comparing `r` to. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
For each sample `r[i]`
    Start with `k = 0`
    While `r[i] > acum[k]`
        Increment `k`
    Now that `r[i] <= acum[k]`, store `k` into `amostra[i]`
```

Translating it to Python:

```
for i in range(M):
    k = 0

    while (r[i] > acum[k]):
        k += 1

    amostra[i] = k
```

So here is the code fixed:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd

def inversao_discreto(p, M):
    amostra = np.zeros(M)
    acum = np.zeros(len(p))
    acum[:] = p

    for i in range(1, len(acum)):
        acum[i] += acum[i - 1]

    r = rd.random_sample(M)

    for i in range(M):
        k = 0

        while (r[i] > acum[k]):
            k += 1

        amostra[i] = k

    return amostra

model = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4])
sample = inversao_discreto(model, 10000)
```

I tried to change as little code as possible to make it work since you are relatively new to Python. Most of the changes I implemented were based on this [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which I recommend you to take a look at since will improve your code, visually speaking.